# Adding alerts for users on a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, alert

I am the admin for a SharePoint 2013 on premises site and am adding alerts for a list on one of our pages. I am able to add each user, name by name. Is there a way to add everyone? We have a email group with everyone's name, but it won't show up on the drop down. Theres gotta be an easier way!
Anyone know if i really have to manu

Comment: What type of email group is that? security or distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to type `NT AUTHORITY\AUTHENTICATED USERS`. it will show that as no result but ignore it and it should be fine. [Refer to this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mpriem/archive/2012/08/17/sharing-permissions-for-authenticated-users-in-sharepoint-2013-preview.aspx).